# Semantic issue after updating Chartboost SDK

Tags: xcode, xcode5, chartboost

I have had the following problem occur after updating to the latest Chartboost SDK in Xcode.

- (void)didCacheInterstitial:(NSString *)location {
  NSLog(@"interstitial cached at location %@", location);
- (void)didDismissInterstitial:(NSString *)location {
  NSLog(@"dismissed interstitial at location %@", location);

[[Chartboost sharedChartboost] cacheInterstitial:location];

The error messages i am getting are:

conflicting parameter types in implementation of 'didCacheinterstitial:': 'CBlocation vs 'NSString*'

cannot initilaze a parameter of type 'CBlocation' with Ivalue of type 'NSString*'

Any help fixing this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Chartboost iOS SDK changes the way named locations are defined. They should now be defined in the Chartboost.h header file. This means that the SDK delegate methods will receive type `CBLocation` instead of `NSString`

See this help site documentation for more details: https://help.chartboost.com/documentation/ios/namedlocations

There were a few other updates in that version, check out the [changelog](https://help.chartboost.com/downloads/ios) for more info.